# Why doesn't "Time#since" not work for me?

Tags: ruby

Why this is not working for me:

```
class Time
  # Return the time difference (as a Float) between now and a specified older Time or parse-able String.
  #   a = Time.now
  #   Time.since(a) # => 8.920116
  #   a.since(a) # => 0.0
  #   Time.since '11:30' # => 28.111561
  #   Time.since '9am' # => 9138.288258
  def self.since(older_time)
    Time.now.since(older_time)
  end

  def since(older_time)
    self - (older_time.kind_of?(Time) ? older_time : Time.parse(older_time))
  end
end

puts Time.since '9am'
```

Error message:

> .rb:13:in `since': undefined method`
>   parse' for Time:Class (NoMethodError)
>     from TimeSince.rb:9:in `since'  from
>   TimeSince.rb:17:in`'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not doing `require 'time'` before it, and so the `Time.parse` method (and every other method in the `Time` class) will be unavailable.

Comment: Technically, the core Time methods will still be available (`Time.new`, `Time.now`, etc.) -- it's just the added Standard Library methods (`Time.parse` being one of them) that require the `require 'time'` statement.